# Tomcat error running war file

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

When I try to run a web app com tomcat I get this error:
FAIL - Encountered exception javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method check

I have put the war file in the webapps folder, then when I click in the "Start" button I get the error "FAIL - Application at context path /Black.ArtespPAP could not be started".

So I tried to deploy the app manually in the deploy from (setting the context, xml file and war path) and I get the javax exception above.

Could anyone help me?

catalina.out log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/tomcat/conf/pap.properties (No such file or directory)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1255)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/tomcat/conf/pap.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:124)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
        ... 36 more
Sep 17, 2012 10:14:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 17, 2012 10:14:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Black.ArtespPAP] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace..

Comment: I have edited the question with the catalina.out output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the logs that the file `/home/ubuntu/tomcat/conf/pap.properties` is missing. It looks like a config file used by the Spring framework (based on the stack trace). Afaik it is not a standard file but an application-specific one, so you would have to dig into your application code or documentation to figure out what it is used for and what it should contain.

Comment: I fixed that and we able to deploy and start it but now it takes forever to open the application and it returns a timeout error in the end. The war file generated with maven has 50mb, is this correct? A war file with 50mb seems too big for me.

Comment: 50mb is not unusual for a war file with many 3rd party jars in it. You could try to move some jars under Tomcat's common lib to make the war file smaller. As for the timeout error, I suggest you open another question for that since it looks like a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked tomcat logs (tomcat/logs/catalina.out and/or your application logs)? Stack traces are there... How do you deploy it manually? Generally, for tomcat, to deploy app, it's enough to copy a .war file into tomcat/webapps folder.

Comment: I copied the war file in the webapps folder but it does not work, when I try to access it returns a 404 error